# How to add class object into NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I am to achieve something with a background thread. I need to add several elements into a mutable array, but I've no idea if I am doing it right with wrapping my own class's object into the array. The code replys me with error message like `NsMutableArray cannot init with a class object` or things like that.

The code's as follows. Would you guys figure out where the problem is? Thanks a lot in advance.

```
// Map is my own class
-(void) toDo:(CGPoint)fromPos toPos:(CGPoint)targetPos aMap:(Map *)aMap  
{
    NSMutableArray * buddy = [[[NSMutableArray init]alloc]autorelease];
    [buddy addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:fromPos]];
    [buddy addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:toPos]];
    [buddy addObject:(Map *)aMap];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(toDoThreadFunc:) withObject:buddy];
}

-(void) toDoThreadFunc:(NSMutableArray *)anArray
{
    CGPoint fromP = [[anArray objectAtIndex:0] CGPointValue];
    CGPoint toP = [[anArray objectAtIndex:1] CGPointValue];
    Map * aM = [anArray objectAtIndex:2];

    [(Map *)aM performSomething:fromP toPos:toP];
}
```

Comment: Syntax should be [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; you trying to init and you have not alloc a mmeory for that... first alloc then init

Comment: C_X is right, you are initialising the object before allocating memory for it. (You should still keep using `autorelease` if needed when not using ARC for your APP).

Comment: really appreiciate both of u thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:[yourObject class]];

//Later
Class yourObject = [array objectAtIndex:0UL];
```

Thanks